# Is possible to get overshoot on bessel filter?

Tags: filters, software-implementation

I tried to use bessel filter from [here](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter/trad.html),
but in the case of a large dataset, I have overshoot.  Since I know a bessel filter shouldn't have overshoot, is this code wrong or am I doing something else wrong?

```
// Sample rate : 1e9
// Cut off Frequency : 50e6

int s=50000;
double[] sample = new double[s];

for(int i=s/2; i<s; i++) {
  sample[i] = 1.0;
}

for (int i = 0; i<sample.length; i++) {
    xv[0] = xv[1];
    xv[1] = xv[2];
    xv[2] = xv[3]; 
    xv[3] = sample[i] / GAIN;
    yv[0] = yv[1]; 
    yv[1] = yv[2]; 
    yv[2] = yv[3]; 
    yv[3] = (xv[0] + xv[3]) + 3 * (xv[1] + xv[2])
          + (  0.3402988787 * yv[0]) 
          + ( -1.4152725242 * yv[1])
          + (  2.0223552191 * yv[2]);
    filteredValue[i] = yv[3];
}
```

All coefficients have been calculated based on source on given website, it might been messy because its used for chebyshev and butterworth filters as well.

Comment: More information would be helpful. Do you have example code or at least a plot that could show what you're asking about?

Comment: example of code you have on website what i used, it automatically generated filter for given parameters. In my case parameters does not different, my graph has large overshoot if i use large dataset (100k elements, for smaller set (50 elements) overshoot is smaller, barely noticeable

Comment: You need to provide much more information than you've given in order to get a good answer. We can't tell if you've done something wrong unless we see some indication of what you've actually done. While the linked page does generate C code that can implement a filter, it is not complete. A full example, or at the bare minimum, plots of what you're seeing would be needed.

Comment: unfortunately i cant add plot because i dont have required reputation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by overshoot. Let's define it as "when filtering a square wave, the max of of the the output should not exceed the steady state of max of the square wave".

In this case your statement "as i know bessel filter shouldnt have overshoot" is wrong. A bessel filter will indeed overshoot. A few first order filters will not overshoot (butterworth, chebychev, ...) but any filter of order > 1 will overshoot.

Comment: +1: A Bessel filter does overshoot. However, there are a few other [filters of order >1 that don't overshoot](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/14035/whats-the-sharpest-frequency-response-for-a-non-causal-low-pass-filter-whose-st).

Comment: Gaussian filters don't overshoot (but also require predicting the future)

Comment: Bessel filters tend to have a very slight overshoot which is "felt" *for the lower orders*. As higher orders come into play, the overshoot converges towards zero, more precisely the filters converges towards an ideal delay, exp(-s). Here's a step response for a sweep from N=2..20: http://imgur.com/SVgSse0 . Gaussian filters do not overshoot, but precise matching is required for any of its approximations of any order (though matching is true for any filter).